# How do I bring a relation/table to first normal form (1NF) when one of the attributes/columns can hold any number of values?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

For example,

- MOVIES (movieid, movietitle)

where *movietitle* can be any number of words, so I believe it's not atomic.

How do you bring something like that to 1NF?

Comment: What's the specific domain of *movietitle*? What are the constraints that apply to that domain? Do you have a real-world and representative set of sample values of that domain? Also, the post so far lacks any description of the business environment of relevance, so please address that issue.

Comment: As it stands, an answer [like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249962/63644) suffices.

Comment: A movie title, regardless of how many words (or characters) are in it, _is_ an atomic value.

Comment: The comment above is correct as long as a given *movietitle* occurrence corresponds to exactly one value of the respective *simple domain*, but we don't know what the domain is in this very particular case; therefore, for the time being, it's impossible to determine with the precision demanded in professional database design all the aspects around first normal form in the scenario at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomic in this sense is a logical concept. Would you consider the integer 123 not atomic because it has more than one digit? 
123 is an agreed upon singular fact, representing  a point on the numbers axis.
A movie title is the same - it represents a singular agreed upon fact, that a movie with that title exists in the real world.
A non atomic value would be “rocky, rocky 2” - a value that specifies 2 facts , and that would violate 1NF.
Same would go for the integer 123, if each digit represents a different fact. For example if 1 represents an item color code and the 23 its size.

HTH